# Netbeans 7.2 ID doesn't start

Tags: plugins, netbeans, netbeans-7.2

I've updated the Netbeans, and now I found this problem restarting the id.

Warning - could not install some modules: CSS Visual Editor - The module CSS Editor was requested in version >= 1.30 but only 1.29 was found. 24 further modules could not be installed due to the above problems.

I've tried to disable manually the plugin, but it did't work. I wouldn't like to reinstall the id, cause that would be a real problem to me...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Don't have a solution, but it seems [we're not the only ones](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=218373)

Comment: Yep, I finally had to reinstall the netbeans. I couldn't find any solution...